# php exec with vboxmanage to start virtual server.

Tags: php, virtualbox

I am trying to do a simple project to start a VirtualBox VM using a PHP script. My server is win 7 ultimate and running php5.3 I am using the vboxmanage.exe to start the server. cmd works great in a batch file or typed right into cmd line.

When I use:

```
exec("path to vboxmange.exe" startvm "vm name");
```

it doesnt work. If I change the code to:

```
exec(dir);
```

it works fine. I did some searching and everyone seemed to mention permissions for IIS_IUSRS. I set it to have read and execute on the vboxmanage.exe and tried to do it for cmd.exe but cant seem to get it to allow me to do this, though it doesnt seem necessary as it can run other cmds like dir.

another theory I have is that exec wraps the entire cmd in "" and this doesnt work when I try to type it in to cmd line manually. I have tried to trim it off but that doesnt work cause exec adds it on so nothing I do before can stop this.

any suggestions for another way to do this or what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

From [`exec` in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the
>   safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed
>   to have .. components in the path to the executable.

Check the value of your `safe_mode_exec_dir` in your `php.ini`. I would guess that it would be fairly restrictive by default.

If that doesn't work, take a look in the comments. Particularly, [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#110131) might be of help to you.

Comment: safe mode is off in my php.ini

Comment: Take a look at that comment I linked you to, may be of help.

Comment: was it the one suggesting to use popen and start /b? or the one after?